# Is there a differnce between tree and branch in this documentation?

Tags: git

[`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) says it gives you the status of the current tree.

However, I'm used to type:

```
git branch -v
```

to see what branches I have.

Are the docs using the terms interchangeably? (tree and branch)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, these are quite different.

For a series of Git definitions of terms, see [the gitglossary](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html).  Here you will find these definitions:

> branch
>
>   A "branch" is an active line of development. The most recent commit on a
>   [branch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_commit)
>   is referred to as the tip of that branch. The tip of the branch is referenced by a branch head, which moves forward as additional development is done on the branch. A single Git
>   [repository](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_repository)
>   can track an arbitrary number of branches, but your working tree is associated with just one of them (the "current" or "checked out" branch), and
>   [HEAD](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_HEAD)
>   points to that branch.

[snippage]

> tree
>
>   Either a
>   [working tree](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_working_tree)
>   , or a
>   [tree object](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_tree_object)
>   together with the dependent
>   [blob](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_blob_object)
>   and tree objects (i.e. a stored representation of a working tree).

The notion of "branch" is defined oddly in Git, with respect to most if not all other Version Control Systems that exist anywhere in the world.  See [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

The "tree" mentioned in `git status` documentation is specifically the "working tree" or "work-tree".  The work-tree is pretty simple: it's where you do your work.  The reason for this is that Git's internal storage for files is in a format usable only to Git itself.  In order for all the *other* computer programs you have on your computer to work with files, and for you to work with them yourself, you need a work area, which is your "work-tree" or "working tree".

What's in your work-tree is *not* in Git at all.  Only Git's internal files are in Git.  The work-tree files may store the same *data*—but in normal, ordinary, every-day computing format—as some internal Git files, or they may not.  The internal files are *versioned*, which is not specifically a Git term (and not mentioned in the Git glossary), but means that Git stores every version you ever asked it to store, more or less permanently,<sup>1</sup> and in a form that *never* changes once stored.  This means that once stored into the Git repository, you can get *every* version of *every* file you, or anyone else, *ever* stored.

---

<sup>1</sup>These versions are stored in *commits*, which are also mostly-permanent and entirely-unchangeable.  Under some conditions, you can rid yourself of—i.e., strip out—some specific commits, but it's deliberately quite difficult (well, other than removing the entire repository, or wiping the hard drive / USB stick / whatever storage medium: but since Git repositories are routinely copied all over the Internet, there are probably 400 more copies Out There somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Before Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), the glossary described a branch as an "active" line of development, which is misleading---a stale and non-moving branch is still a branch.

See [commit eef1cea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eef1ceabd8200d1160b015b049a896612a74f0e8) (23 Nov 2020) by [Sergey Organov (`sorganov`)](https://github.com/sorganov).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c9f1f44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9f1f4412cdb7fdb5da47fd1c5bc9614cc9aa48c), 14 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`glossary`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eef1ceabd8200d1160b015b049a896612a74f0e8): improve "branch" definition
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sergey Organov</sup>

> The old phrasing is at least questionable, if not wrong, as there are a lot of branches out there that didn't see active development for years, yet they are still branches, ready to become active again any time.

The description now begins with:

> A "branch" is a line of development.

(no more "active")

It still differ from working tree, as [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107232/6309): an *old* stale branch would still be there, no matter what the *current* working tree (set of files you want a status of) is.